# Pass user input for bash script downloaded with CURL

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to automate installation of Google SDK on a Linux VM and I need some expertise from you.

I can run following pipeline (which is a part of a script):

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

but then it asks for some user input like installation directory and some other confirmations.
I was wondering how can I integrate answers to those questions within above pipeline.

I'm aware of something like:

```
echo -e "ans1\nans2\n" | bash_script.sh
```

but that doesn't fit in my case. The result I get is:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" | curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   443  100   443    0     0  31642      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31642
Downloading Google Cloud SDK install script: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
######################################################################## 100.0%
Running install script from: /tmp/tmp.l0LXFQOlyx/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
which curl
curl -# -f https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
#################################################################################################################################### 100.0%

Installation directory (this will create a google-cloud-sdk subdirectory) (/root):
```

So it still waits for my input.

This is probably something trivial for Linux oriented experts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why your try does not work?

Comment: Added the result.

Comment: Try with https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

you tell bash *take **everything** I feed to your standard input and execute it as a command*. This means that standard input is already "used up". Whatever you would feed in advance the stdin pipeline at the point of `... |bash` would also be part of this command, and not of a later input of the command.

Your `echo` solution is meaningless, since it passes input to `curl` (which does not need stdin, and everything you feed into it, gets lost anyway).

I wonder why you insist in having this pipeline. I would not want to fetch something from the web and then feed it into bash, without even looking at it. IMO the cleanest solution is to separate these steps: Store the result from `curl` to some temporary file, and if curl returned exit code zero, run this file from bash. At this point, you can feed its stdin if you like.

Comment: It's not like I really insist and actually your idea of separating those things is quite nice and probably might be easier to me to cope with (I'm not Linux expert). So I'll try to follow your suggestion and see where I'll end up :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user1934428 suggestion, I have separated the commands to smth like:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com --output sdk-install.sh && sh sdk-install.sh --install-dir=/tmp --disable-prompts
```

That satisfies my needs.

Thanks.